# How to debug Rust and WebAssembly program with VSCode and CodeLLDB?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, rust, webassembly, codelldb

I am writing [Rust and WebAssembly program](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html). I wanted to debug Rust and WebAssembly program with VSCode and CodeLLDB, but I got an error. I can debug simple Rust program, but fail to debug Rust and WebAssembly program. **Steps to reproduce the error are shown below.**

Clone the Rust and WebAssembly project template with this command:

`cargo generate --git https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack-template`

Then, type the project name. I used "foo".
Add a test in foo/src/lib.rs

```
mod utils;

use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

// When the `wee_alloc` feature is enabled, use `wee_alloc` as the global
// allocator.
#[cfg(feature = "wee_alloc")]
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern {
    fn alert(s: &str);
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn greet() {
    alert("Hello, foo!");
}

// add this test.
#[test]
fn foo_test() {
    assert_eq!(1, 1);
}
```

Place a breakpoint at foo_test(). Then, create a launch.json file.

`.vscode/launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug unit tests in library 'foo'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--lib",
                    "--package=foo"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "foo",
                    "kind": "lib"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug integration test 'web'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--test=web",
                    "--package=foo"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "web",
                    "kind": "test"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

After I started "Debug unit tests in library 'foo'", I got an error message, "Cargo has produced no matching compilation artifacts". What can I do to fix this error?

My setup: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3, Visual Studio Code(VSCode) 1.55.1, CodeLLDB 1.6.1, cargo 1.51.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be not the most helpful answer, but the answer is you currently can't - there is an open issue on wasm-bindgen repo tracking future support for debugging but it's not yet supported: https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2389

Note that even when it will be, you'll need to use browser DevTools not CodeLLDB for WebAssembly debugging, since you need a JavaScript-capable environment.